# When I grow up, I will be a nurse and look after patients.Why use simple present in the clause?

Tags: subordinate-clauses

**grow up** is a thing that will happen in the future. Why not use the future tense here? I am a little confused.

Comment: Grow up will happen in the future, but "**when** I grow up" describes a point after it has happened.  This is narrated from the perspective of when you are already grown up so at that point, it is present tense.

Comment: The simple present has often a future meaning in when-clauses.

Comment: It seems not a accurate explanation, I will just remember it as a custom usage.

Comment: In the same way, if clauses aren't inflected in the subjunctive mood. In linguistics, that is called analytic language. It's not *custom usage*, it's standard. Also, there are probably languages in which future tense is only signaled by modifiers, but never inflected. On the other hand, it depends on style and I can only speak about the informal style - it's probably not wrong to inflect the tense in when clauses, because English is not purely analytic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word **when** is really the deal breaker here. It does in fact indicate a specific event taking the future.

Consider:

> I'll believe it **when** I see it.

You might want to argue that instances exist in which the same word, "when," does NOT indicate the future. Such as:

> When I see you my entire universe fills with dazzling light.

Well, not quite. In this instance, the word "when" is short for "**whenever**," which is not the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Because English doesn't use the so-called future (the "will" form) in "if" or "when" clauses. *

I'm sorry, but that is the whole of the answer. One can speculate about why that has come about, but it's simply an arbitrary fact of English grammar.

*There is one apparent group of exceptions: with "if" (not "when") and second or third person subjects (not first person), phrases like "If he will wait for me, ... " do occur. But here, "will" is not the modal which forms the so-called future, but a vestige of the original meaning of "will" = "want" or "be willing". "If he will wait for me" means something like "If he is willing to wait for me". This form is often a sort of implied request.