# The next time when you [will]..., Main Clause

Tags: future-tense, adverbial-phrases

Can we you use an Attributive Clause with Future Tense inside an Adverbial Clause of Time?

What is the difference in the meanings if one exists?

> The next time when you meet him, he will...
>
> The next time when you will meet him, he will...

Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't need the "when" or the first "will". "You meet him" is a present tense relative clause modifying the nominal "next time".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When I grow up, I will be a nurse and look after patients.Why use simple present in the clause?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/124168/when-i-grow-up-i-will-be-a-nurse-and-look-after-patients-why-use-simple-present)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The next time you meet him...

You have met him before and will meet him again.  "the next time you meet him" refers to that future occasion on which the two of you shall meet again.

> As you can see, today I am dressed as an admiral. The next time you meet me, I will be
>   wearing an ape suit.

With "when":

> The next time, when you will meet him...

You have not (necessarily) met him yet, but the next time (something happens),  you will meet him.

> The next time the chess club meets, when you will meet him [the
>   world-renowned chess player, say], is in February.

The *when*-clause there simply adds info which is temporally relevant; the clause  does not restrict or modify "next time".

Comment: Hi, this page https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/numbers/time says that "the time when" introduces a clause which adds the necessary information and is not adverbial of time, so that we can use "when" or "that" or omit a conjunction. The following sentence "Facebook is starting to think about the time when Mark Zuckerberg will no longer be at its helm.", which I took from CNN's website, contains the same "the time + when + will"

Comment: **the time when** simply refers to an occasion or a moment or a period, one which might have taken place already or might not. *I was thinking about the time (when) we rode our bikes 100 miles to the beach.* or *She was thinking about (the time) when they would all be off to college and the house would be empty.*  That construction has nothing to do with the original question, which asks about **the next time** and its use with the future **will**.

Answer (score -2):

“The next time when you meet him, he will...”

“The next time when you will meet him, he will...”

There really isn’t a difference, they both mean the same thing. If the “when” wasn’t included then the second sentence, (the one with will,) it gives the reader the extra bit, saying that the woman WILL meet him, and he WILL..., but, “The next time you meet him, he will...” gives off the possibility that the woman could not end up meeting him. Including the “When” in the first sentence dismisses the idea that she could end up not meeting him, because typically, “When,” means “Definitely,” and “If,” means “Possibly.”